# MobX State Tree: Type of Action Parameter in Union

Tags: typescript, mobx-state-tree

In MST, when creating a union type from models which define the same action with different parameter types, I would expect to be able to call an action on an instance of the union type. Unfortunately, the parameter type seems to be an intersection type rather than a union type.

In the below example, `Item#updatePayload` expects `string & boolean[][]`, but should accept `I extends SnapshotOrInstance<typeof Foo> ? string | undefined : boolean[][]` <del>`string | boolean[][]`</del> imho.

Am I somehow using this the wrong way? If so, how would I have to change the models to get what I expect?

```js
const Foo = types.model({
  id: types.identifier,
  payload: types.maybe(types.string),
}).actions((self) => ({
  updatePayload(payload?: string) {
    self.payload = payload;
  },
}));

const Bar = types.model({
  id: types.identifier,
  payload: types.array(types.array(types.boolean)),
}).actions((self) => ({
  updatePayload(payload: boolean[][]) {
    applySnapshot(self.payload, payload);
  },
}));

const Item = types.union(Foo, Bar);
const Bucket = types.model({
  items: types.map(Item),
}).actions((self) => ({
  updateItemPayload(id: string, payload?: string | boolean[][]) {
    const item = self.items.get(id);
    item && item.updatePayload(payload);
  },
}));
```

### Edit

In fact, the signature of `Item#updatePayload` should (I assume) rather be  as follows

```js
updatePayload<I extends SnapshotOrInstance<typeof Item>>(payload: I extends SnapshotOrInstance<typeof Foo> ? string | undefined : boolean[][])
```

Comment: Are you sure it's MST holding you back, rather then TypeScript itself?

Comment: Well, either would work without the other, but since I'm using both (it's like with MST vs. MobX only, the benefits far outweigh the disadvantages of using TS vs. just JS), they need to work in combination - and as far as I understand, they're meant to!

Comment: I mean TS usually requires you to have generic handler when overloading the methods and differentiate manually on a type of argument inside.

Comment: You're absolutely right, it would be even better for the parameter to be of a conditional type (e.g. `I extends Foo ? string | undefined : boolean[][]`), not a type union as I originally wrote. I'll update my question accordingly.

Comment: Still doesn't work though, or it's ok now?

Comment: Nope, the TS signature is created by the MST model, I don't think I can do anything about that. Just looking to get some input before I possibly open an issue - I think I'll do that now.

Comment: Here we go: [the issue](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-state-tree/issues/1371)